# Does the queued TRIM support in SATA 3.1 require support from the SATA controller, or just from the OS and the SSD?

Tags: linux, sata, btrfs, trim

I am contemplating expanding the storage on my home server with a SATA expansion card and wonder if the card has to support *queued TRIM* to use it or if it is just an OS+SSD thing.

#### Hardware example

My server is old (PCIe 2.0) and I'm not interested in cutting-edge technology so I am looking at a used or "new-old-stock" card based on the [LSI SAS 2008](https://www.servethehome.com/lsi-sas-2008-raid-controller-hba-information/) controller from 2008. There are numerous cards using this controller, and as an example we can look at the [LSI 9240-8i](https://www.cnet.com/products/lsi-megaraid-sas-9240-8i-storage-controller-raid-sata-6gb-s-sas-pcie-2-0-x8-series/) card. I am not going to use the built-in RAID versions, but rather use it as simple straight-through expansion cards to give me 8 x SATA 6 Gb/s ports.

#### SATA 3.0 vs 3.1 and queued TRIM.

I use btrfs on Linux and I want to use queued TRIM. According to the [btrfs man page](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=Manpage/btrfs(5)&oldid=33037#MOUNT_OPTIONS),

> Queued TRIM requires newer than SATA revision 3.1 **chipsets** and devices.

Ok, and the Wikipedia article about [SATA revision 3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#SATA_revision_3.1) has this to say:

> Released in **July 2011**, SATA revision 3.1 introduced or changed the following features:
>
> - […]
> - Queued TRIM Command, improves solid-state drive performance.

Then looking at the Wikipedia article for [Trim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trim_(computing)#ATA):

> The TRIM command specification has been standardized as part of the AT Attachment (ATA) interface standard […]. TRIM is implemented under the DATA SET MANAGEMENT command […] supported by both parallel (IDE, PATA) and serial (SATA) ATA hardware.
>
> A drawback of the original ATA TRIM command is that it was defined as a non-queueable command and therefore could not easily be mixed with a normal workload of queued read and write operations. SATA 3.1 introduced a queued TRIM **command** to remedy this.

#### Summary

I believe that the *controller* attached to my computer does not care about the SATA 3.1 queued TRIM command, it is a normal ATA command sent directly from the operating system to the drive over the SATA bus just like any other ATA command. Is there a flaw in my thinking?

Comment: I bought the controller I wanted and the links show up as SATA 3.1 and not SATA 3.0. Maybe I'll self-answer this when I've figure out how to actually _verify_ this.

Comment: And did you figure it out? It's a good question, shame it hasn't received an answer yet.